# Layout in mathematical model using align

Tags: align

I would like all "columns" in my 'aling' to begin text from left to right (left flush).

I have included my code below, which gives the following result:

[image]

As seen in picture:

- The text in the first column is from right to left
- The text in the second column is from left to right
- The text in the third column is from right to left

### TEX file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    \text{min} \qquad & \sum_{e\in \mathcal{E}} \sum_{r\in  \mathcal{R}_e} c^r_e x^r_e + \sum_{d \in \mathcal{D}} c^-_d s_d^- + \sum_{d \in \mathcal{D}} c^+_d s^+_d \label{MP1} \\ 
    \text{s.t.} \qquad & \sum_{e\in \mathcal{E}} \sum_{r\in  \mathcal{R}_e} a^r_{ed} x^r_e + s_d^- -s_d^+ = b_d & \forall d \in \mathcal{D} \label{MP2} \\
    & \sum_{r\in  \mathcal{R}_e} x^r_e = 1 & \forall e \in \mathcal{E} \label{MP3} \\
    & x^r_e\in \{ 0,1\} & \forall e \in \mathcal{E}, \forall r \in \mathcal{R}_e \label{MP4} \\
    & 0 \leq s_d^- \leq u_d^- & \forall d \in \mathcal{D} \label{MP5} \\
    & 0 \leq s_d^+ \leq u_d^+ & \forall d \in \mathcal{D} \label{MP6}
\end{align}


\end{document}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you observed, `align` alternates between `r` (right aligned) and `l` (left alinged) columns. To just get left aligned columns, you cann add `&` so "skip"  the `r` columns:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    &\text{min} \qquad && \sum_{e\in \mathcal{E}} \sum_{r\in  \mathcal{R}_e} c^r_e x^r_e + \sum_{d \in \mathcal{D}} c^-_d s_d^- + \sum_{d \in \mathcal{D}} c^+_d s^+_d \label{MP1} \\ 
   & \text{s.t.} \qquad && \sum_{e\in \mathcal{E}} \sum_{r\in  \mathcal{R}_e} a^r_{ed} x^r_e + s_d^- -s_d^+ = b_d && \forall d \in \mathcal{D} \label{MP2} \\
    &&& \sum_{r\in  \mathcal{R}_e} x^r_e = 1 && \forall e \in \mathcal{E} \label{MP3} \\
    &&& x^r_e\in \{ 0,1\} && \forall e \in \mathcal{E}, \forall r \in \mathcal{R}_e \label{MP4} \\
    &&& 0 \leq s_d^- \leq u_d^- && \forall d \in \mathcal{D} \label{MP5} \\
    &&& 0 \leq s_d^+ \leq u_d^+ && \forall d \in \mathcal{D} \label{MP6}
\end{align}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, for the excellent explanation. It was exactly what I wanted.

Comment: It is only my sensation....:-) I often read the thoughts of my students and many have told me that I can predict.

Answer (score 8):

You also can have this layout with the  dedicated `optidef` package. I changed the numbering so that the constraints are subequations of the first line:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[short]{optidef}

\begin{document}

\begin{mini!}
  {\qquad}{ \sum_{e\in \mathcal{E}} \sum_{r\in \mathcal{R}_e} c^r_e x^r_e + \sum_{d \in \mathcal{D}} c^-_d s_d^- + \sum_{d \in \mathcal{D}} c^+_d s^+_d \tag{1}}{\label{MP1}}{}
%
\addConstraint{}{\sum_{e\in \mathcal{E}} \sum_{r\in \mathcal{R}_e} a^r_{ed} x^r_e + s_d^- -s_d^+ = b_d\qquad }{\forall d \in \mathcal{D} \label{MP2}}
\addConstraint{}{\sum_{r\in \mathcal{R}_e} x^r_e = 1}{\forall e \in \mathcal{E} \label{MP3}}
\addConstraint{}{x^r_e\in \{ 0,1\}}{\forall e \in \mathcal{E}, \forall r \in \mathcal{R}_e \label{MP4}}
\addConstraint{}{0 \leq s_d^- \leq u_d^- }{\forall d \in \mathcal{D} \label{MP5}}
\addConstraint{}{0 \leq s_d^+ \leq u_d^+}{\forall d \in \mathcal{D} \label{MP6}}
\end{mini!}

\end{document}
```

[image]